# Ассоциация расширения файлов собственного формата

Tags: android

Полазил в гугле, не нашел решения.
Суть в том что нужно ассоциировать свой формат фалов с своим приложением. Нажимаешь на формат открывается приложение .
Буду благодарен на хоть что то ( куда копать )

Comment: хм а контент провайдер не поможет?
или посмотрите тут

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Answer (score 5):

Ну искать лучше на английском же: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension

Вцелом, @rasmisha правильно подметил. Добавляете фильтры к своему активити главному и пишите логику обработки. Подозреваю, что в Bundle(в параметре onCreate вашего главного активити) будут соответствующие параметры для файла: местоположение, название и прочее. Но в любом случае эта информация также вам понадобится.

Comment: > Ну искать лучше на английском же: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension

ну с другой стороны теперь на нашем форуме есть какие-то размышления на эту тему

Comment: которые будут действительно полезными, когда автор разберется в вопросе и отпишется здесь.

Comment: Разберусь и обещаю отписаться с примерами кода.